# That deep Drone / Ambient texture

Tags: drone, ambience, reverb, sound-design, production

Hi,
Always asked myself how to achieve that deep sound using reverb like in Kerovnian, Megaptera or Amon productions... I tried with no success cuting freqencies below 40 and above 2K with large hall at 60%.
Any idea someone please?

Answer (score 5):

Source-->Reverb-->Compression-->EQ-->Reverb-->EQ.

If that ends up being too wide you could also consider:

Source-->Stereo Reverb-->Mono Reverb-->EQ-->Compression-->Mono Reverb.

If the tail ends up too long, you can just put a gate with a very gentle release (500-750ms).

If you do it right you should totally scare the crap out of yourself.

Comment: Worked just great.

Comment: Yeah!  You can use it on anything.  Try switching stuff up too, throw  a flanger or distortion or pitch-shifter into the chain and see what happens.  Works great with higher voicings too, flutes, clarinets, oboes.

Comment: Great chain exemples, thanks! It's sound more close to what I want to do but maybe I lack experience working with EQs because the sound become "muffled" .. I work by ear and with a creative not technical approach, it should come from there.. Or does it come from my reverb preset? By the way the correlation meter is very chaotic because of wide ambiance (checked in mono)!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that every reverb unit has a low-pass filter built-in.  They usually sit somewhere around 10-12k when you first open them up.  Just play around with it till you get enough high-end for your liking.  Don't forget though that if you're running reverbs in series you're naturally going to start losing high frequency content.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can achieve better results constructing textures from various sources than trying to create it with huge reverb. Some low freq pads, middle freq strings + low freq filter + some very high pitched sounds at very low volume etc. Everything should be equalized right. Take a texture as a composition and add elements which you need.

Answer (score 2):

http://hypermammut.sourceforge.net/paulstretch/

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the timefreezer plugin, 
http://www.timefreezer.net/

I'd avoid the left link, lots of vocalising going on in that, but one on right gives some impression of it's potential usefulness for making soundscapes.

Bitof compression goes a long way in the bass, and a tiny boost around 40-50 herz. Reverb can give a sense of space and dimension, but too much is just sonic mud.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers!
In fact I'm not trying to create texture by itself but rather this (reverbered) ambience: confined, scary, giving the impression of being isolated .. or wide, airy and deep.
I cheked few tracks for references: the audio spectrum looks very small,from 40/60Hz to 2000kHz in general. But there is still a presence, it's clear... Is it just work on equalization? When you listen to Amon - El Kehl - Rise of Thermouthis, it is only white noise filtered and modulated yet something I find emerges through the atmosphere, the reverberation ..

Comment: What is "Amon - El Kehl - Rise of Thermouthis"? I can't find any reference to this no matter what search engine I use.